# Placing content in columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget

There are 3 skills lines and i want them to be placed one next to another, in 3 columns, and i want to create the 4th column too!

Originally, it's like this

_

_

_

_

and i want like this

__________     _________     ______________  ________________

__________    _________      ______________  ________________

_________     __________     ______________  _______________

```css
/* About Us
--------------------------------------------------------*/
 

}

.teamSkill {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
p.skill {
    clear: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.bar {
    background-color: #7b133c;
    border-radius: 11px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0 0 2px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
 width: 22px;
}

.teamSkill:hover .percent100 {width: 100%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent95 {width: 95%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent90 {width: 90%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent85 {width: 85%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent80 {width: 80%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent75 {width: 75%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent70 {width: 70%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent65 {width: 65%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent60 {width: 60%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent55 {width: 55%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent50 {width: 50%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent45 {width: 45%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent40 {width: 40%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent35 {width: 35%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent30 {width: 30%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent25 {width: 25%;}
.teamSkill:hover .percent20 {width: 20%;}

p.percent {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 6px;
    text-align: right;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.6s ease-in 0s;
}
.ie8 p.percent {
    display:none;
}
.teamSkill:hover p.percent {
    opacity: 1;
}
.ie8 .teamSkill:hover p.percent {
    display:block;
}


.statsWrap {
 width: 130px;
 margin: 10px;
 float: left;
}
.stats {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.statDummy {
    margin-top: 100%;
}
.statInfo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #7b133c;
    border-radius: 50%;
 text-align: center;
}
.statNumber {
 font-size: 60px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 padding-top: 24px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.statNumberMedium {
 font-size: 50px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 padding-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.statNumberSmall {
 font-size: 36px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 padding-top: 38px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.statText {
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale(0);
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: -25px;
}
.stats:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
 z-index: 10;
}
.stats:hover .statNumber {
    transform: scale(.6);
}
.stats:hover .statText {
    transform: scale(.6);
 opacity: 1;
}

 
.twitter {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-twitter.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.facebook {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-facebook.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.digg {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-digg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.vimeo {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-vimeo.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.youtube {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-youtube.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.skype {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-skype.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.linkedin {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-linkedin.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.dropbox {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-dropbox.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.twitter-white {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-twitter-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.facebook-white {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-facebook-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.digg-white {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-digg-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.vimeo-white {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-vimeo-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.youtube-white {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-youtube-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.skype-white {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-skype-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.linkedin-white {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-linkedin-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
.dropbox-white {background: url("../images/icons/icon-social-dropbox-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
 
 
 
/* Services
--------------------------------------------------------*/
 
#services {
 padding-top: 0px;
}
.servicesContainer {
 padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.serviceItem {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor: default;
    height: 236px;
    position: relative;
    width: 236px;
 margin: 20px auto;
}
.serviceInfoWrap, .serviceInfo {
    height: 196px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 196px;
}
.serviceInfoWrap {
    background: url("../images/bg.html") repeat scroll 0 0 #F9F9F9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 3px rgba(115, 114, 23, 0.8) inset;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
.serviceInfo > div {
    background-position: center center;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.serviceInfo .serviceInfoFront {
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.serviceInfo .serviceInfoBack {
    background:#7b133c;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.ie8 .serviceInfo .serviceInfoBack {
    display: none;
}
.copywriting, .copywriting .serviceInfoFront {background-image: url(../images/services/copywriting.jpg);}
.creativity, .creativity .serviceInfoFront {background-image: url(../images/services/creativity.jpg);}
.production, .production .serviceInfoFront {background-image: url(../images/services/production.jpg);}
.development, .development .serviceInfoFront {background-image: url(../images/services/development.jpg);}
.photography, .photography .serviceInfoFront {background-image: url(../images/services/photography.jpg);}
.strategy, .strategy .serviceInfoFront {background-image: url(../images/services/strategy.jpg);}

.serviceInfo h3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.serviceInfo p {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px 0;
}

.serviceIcon {
 width: 35px;
 height: 35px;
 margin: 20px auto 10px auto;
}
 
.creativity .serviceIcon {background-image: url("../images/icons/icon-creativity.png");}
.development .serviceIcon {background-image: url("../images/icons/icon-app-development.png");}
.strategy .serviceIcon {background-image: url("../images/icons/icon-brand-strategy.png");}
.copywriting .serviceIcon {background-image: url("../images/icons/icon-copywriting.png");}
.photography .serviceIcon {background-image: url("../images/icons/icon-photography.png");}
.production .serviceIcon {background-image: url("../images/icons/icon-HD-video.png");}

.serviceItem:hover .serviceInfoFront {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
}
.serviceItem:hover .serviceInfoBack {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.ie8 .serviceItem:hover .serviceInfoBack {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 </div>
            
            
             
                <h3 class="sectionTitle">Skills</h3>
                <div class="teamSkill">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">Client Liasing</p>
                            <div class="bar percent90">
                            <p class="percent">90%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">Client Lunches</p>
                            <div class="bar percent100">
                            <p class="percent">100%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">i devices</p>
                            <div class="bar percent90">
                            <p class="percent">90%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">Driving</p>
                            <div class="bar percent40">
                            <p class="percent">40%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">MS Word</p>
                            <div class="bar percent25">
                            <p class="percent">25%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
             
                <h3 class="sectionTitle">Skills</h3>
                <div class="teamSkill">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">Photoshop</p>
                            <div class="bar percent90">
                            <p class="percent">90%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">Illustrator</p>
                            <div class="bar percent80">
                            <p class="percent">80%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">i devices</p>
                            <div class="bar percent90">
                            <p class="percent">90%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">Movies</p>
                            <div class="bar percent60">
                            <p class="percent">60%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">Cleaning</p>
                            <div class="bar percent25">
                            <p class="percent">25%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
             
                <h3 class="sectionTitle">Skills</h3>
                <div class="teamSkill">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">HTML</p>
                            <div class="bar percent90">
                            <p class="percent">90%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">PHP</p>
                            <div class="bar percent60">
                            <p class="percent">60%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">Coffee</p>
                            <div class="bar percent70">
                            <p class="percent">70%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">Shopping</p>
                            <div class="bar percent100">
                            <p class="percent">100%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="skill">Shoes</p>
                            <div class="bar percent80">
                            <p class="percent">80%</p></div>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, there are three possible approaches here.

- Tables
- Layout helpers (like Bootstrap or Pure)
- Inline blocks

**Inline**, is the quickest fix. In your `.team-skill` class, set a `max-width` of your choosing (180px would do for now), then add:

```
display: inline-block;
float: left;
```

Now depending on your window size, most of the team-skill divs ought to be snugging up to one another, column-style. However this approach isn't robust, and it doesn't take much to break it. Let's try **tables**...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      ///- Stick a team-skill div in here -///
    </td>
    <td>
      ///- Put another team-skill div in here -///
    </td>
    <td>
      ///- And so on... -///
    </td>
  </tr>   
</table>
```

Tables are nice 1) because they're native and require no plugins or frameworks, and 2) Well... umm... yes. They're nice and easy. They're certainly more robust than the inline solution, but they're not considered a responsive solution. If you want these columns to look nice across a wide variety of devices, get yourself acquainted with a **layout framework**. Here's a few:

- [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/)
- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [Pure](http://purecss.io/)

These frameworks will give you powerful tools with which to build any layout you want, including your 4 columns.

Comment: Which is why `inline` isn't the best solution -- It's the quick fix, but it breaks easily. Try another approach.

Comment: But i used tables :(((

Comment: Ah ha! Well then, could you share a JSfiddle of your table-ified code?

Comment: Awesome! :) I just finished up a JSfiddle demo-ing the tables. Here it is for future reference: http://jsfiddle.net/4mxx3am1/1/ Note that the formatting isn't ideal, but they do stay next to one another.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of ways using the developer tools, until i got what i needed, then copied and pasted into dreamweaver. Looks great now! thank you!